# a:hover:after inside of div appears at rightside of div not end of text of a

Tags: html, css, hover

I am having trouble getting the a:hover:after to appear after the text of the  tag.  The content appears at the end of the `<div>`.  Is there a way to get it to appear right after the text of the `<a>`?  I don't want the after content to push other elements on hover.

```
<div>
  <a href="#">test</a>
</div>

a:hover:after{
  display: inline-block;
  content: ">>";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreadjr/AGDbH/380/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking out the `right:0` seems to do what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/a6AA9/

Is this what you mean?

The `margin-left` tip above is a good one as well

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
```

Keep just

```
a:hover:after{
    display: inline-block;
    content: ">>";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AGDbH/381/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the position absolute and put an small margin.

```
content: ">>";
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
```

Comment: That works, but i forgot to mention, i wanted it absolute because i didn't want it to push other elements around.